# Do I still provoke an opportunity attack when squeezing through an ally’s space?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack

Situation. Battle has erupted down a corridor 10 feet wide, fighter ally on one side, goblin1 on the other therefore taking up the ten foot wide corridor. My rogue needs to pass through the fighters space to get to the other side to attack another goblin2 standing next to his goblin1 mate in battle. As my rogue passes through does goblin1 get an opportunity attack on me? Also since I am now next to the fighter I can sneak attack without advantage on goblin 1?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Have a look at the [tour] and at the [help] in case you need guidance in posting questions&answer! Usually you should ask one question per post: I suggest that you post the other question about Sneak Attack in another one.

Comment: Okay thanks Eddymage

Answer (score 4):

**No** and **yes**, respectively.

Moving through an ally's space is [difficult terrain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures), and [costs twice as much movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DifficultTerrain) to do.  However, the only thing that provokes opportunity attacks is [leaving the reach of an enemy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks).  You can move through the fighter's space without provoking, but you will provoke if any part of your movement leaves goblin 1's reach.

Once you are past the ally, you can make melee attacks on goblin 1.  Since the fighter is another enemy of the goblin, is within 5 feet of the target, and is not incapacitated, [you don't need advantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#SneakAttack) on the attack roll to get sneak attack providing you don't have disadvantage.

"Squeezing" is probably not relevant to your question.  It's what happens when a creature tries to move through a space physically too small for it.  While you are in such a space, [you have disadvantage on attack rolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#SqueezingintoaSmallerSpace), which would prevent you from making sneak attacks.  However, the situation you describe does not involve squeezing.

Comment: So by difficult terrain that means the five foot of space now takes up 10 feet of my movement? Also if instead of stopping next to the fighter I continue my movement ten feet past him, will that then provoke an opportunity attack?

Comment: Solid answer, but can you please add support with where the rules show this is true?

Comment: @JeremyRaven you provoke an opportunity attack if you, at any point in time, move to a square outside of the goblin's reach (which I assume is 5ft). Thus, if you move 10 feet past the fighter, you likely also left the goblin's reach and thus do provoke an opportunity attack. Side note: if you were to provide a simple drawing showing the squares & character positions, it'd be easier to give a precise answer :)

Comment: @JeremyRaven Yes to both of your questions; I have edited the answer to reflect this.